Firebase Function CORS Issue: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" Header Issue Despite Correct Setup
I'm encountering a persistent CORS issue while working with a Firebase HTTPS function in my Vite.js React app, specifically when trying to integrate OAuth.
Problem:
The following error is thrown when I try to send a request from my frontend to a Firebase Cloud Function:

callback:1 Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/my-project-id/us-central1/youtube/youtubeaccesstoken' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
`

I have set credentials: 'include' on my fetch request, and it seems that Firebase is not returning the required Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true header, even though I have tried setting CORS both implicitly and explicitly.
What I’ve Tried:

Firebase Function Setup: I've used Firebase's onRequest with cors:
true to allow CORS

   
       const {
         onRequest
       } = require('firebase-functions/v2/https');
   
       exports.youtube = onRequest({
         timeoutSeconds: 360,
         cors: true
       }, (req, res) => {
         // Handle the preflight OPTIONS request
         if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
           res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:5173');
           res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
           res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, Content-Type');
           res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
           res.status(204).send('');
           return;
         }
   
         // Handle the actual request
         res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:5173');
         res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
   
         youtubeService(req, res);
       });
   
   



Client-Side Fetch: The client-side fetch request is set to include credentials:



fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5001/my-project-id/us-central1/youtube/youtubeaccesstoken', {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    code,
    state,
    userId
  }),
});




I have also tried a different approach for my firebase function as i am using express.



const youtubeService = express();
youtubeService.use(express.json());
youtubeService.use(cookieParser());

const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:5173", // Use specific origin instead of true
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS",
  credentials: true, // Allow credentials
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
};

youtubeService.use(cors(corsOptions));

//and the rest of the REST endpoints





exports.youtube = onRequest({
    timeoutSeconds: 360,
    cors: true,
  },
  youtubeService
);



Expected Behavior:
The Firebase function should allow cross-origin requests, returning the necessary CORS headers, particularly Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true, when using credentials: 'include' on the frontend.
Things to Consider:

Firebase is supposed to handle the preflight request implicitly, but
I've explicitly set it just to be sure.
All other CORS headers seem to be working fine, except for
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

.

In regard to your last attempt, where you tried to handle cors in your own express router, you will need to pass cors: false (or not mention it) in the HttpsOptions object that you are feeding to onRequest(opts, handler). If you use true here, the internal cors instance will be injected and will handle the request before your express router is even called.

If you set cors: true in your function configuration, you shouldn't write any code at all to handle the OPTIONS request or deal with cors headers at all.  You also shouldn't try to use an express app with cors middleware.  The functions framework will do all that for you automatically.
A minimal example is provided in the documentation.  Note that the example code just handles the request normally without being concerned about cors implementation details.  Start with that minimal example, make sure it works, then add more code as needed.
If you want to use an express app, don't try to invoke that in the handler for an onRequest function.  The only correct way to use an express app with Cloud Functions on Firebase is also covered in the documentation.  Notice that you just app the app to onRequest directly, and there is no function callback.  If you use an express app, then you should handle cors yourself - the Firebase SDK will not handle that for you.

I went through the documentation as you suggested, and I understand that Firebase Functions handles CORS implicitly when we use cors: true. I initially tried without any manual CORS handling, but the error I'm seeing isn't related to the typical Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
Access to fetch at ... from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. 

Also ,The service works fine with a GET request, but this error occurs when I send a POST request.

If you did exactly what the documentation said, but it didn't work, then you should consider filing a bug report on firebase-functions with your code and steps to reproduce the problem.  Also you could send feedback using the button at the top of the page of documentation that you found was inaccurate.
